# Is there a general way to solve this modular equation?

Tags: nt.number-theory

There is an ordered set $M$ with $N$ numbers in it (and $M_n$ is the $n$-th number in $M$). Let $L_k$ be the sum of the first $k$ numbers in $M$.

Consider equation $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} 3^k 2^{-L_{k+1}} \equiv 1 \bmod 3^N$

For example, if $N=1 \Rightarrow 3^0 2^{-L_1} \equiv 1 \bmod 3^1$ or $2^{-L_1}\equiv 1 \bmod 3$, which is only possible if $-L_1\equiv 0 \bmod 2 \Rightarrow M_1 \equiv 0 \bmod 2$ (which is to say, "if $M$ contains $1$ number and solves the equation above, the number that $M$ contains must be even")

Is there a general way we can use to find all "modular restrictions" for all numbers in $M$ for any given size ($N$) of $M$? It gets really hard brute forcing even for $N=4$.

Comment: `$3$<sup>$1$</sup>` is not a proper way to write MathJax code. It should say `$3^1$`. See my edits to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no simple formula for the solutions to the given congruence. Still, they can be computed iteratively as follows.

First, we notice that $2^m = (3-1)^m \equiv (-1)^m \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \binom{m}{i} (-3)^i \pmod{3^N}$. Then the left-hand side of the congruence in question can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} 3^k (-1)^{L_{k+1}} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \binom{- L_{k+1}}{i} (-3)^i \equiv \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} 3^m \sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^{L_{k+1}+m-k} \binom{- L_{k+1}}{m-k} \pmod{3^N}$$

Next, we fix the parities of $L_1,\dots,L_N$, where $L_1\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ and the others can be arbitrary. Then, we compute iteratively $L_2,\dots,L_{N-1}$ in parametric form by considering the above congruence modulo $3^l$ for $l=2,\dots,N$, dividing it by $3^{l-1}$, and solving the resulting linear congruence with respect to $L_{l-1}$.

Finally, we obtain $M_k = L_k - L_{k-1}$.

Hence, this approach constructs a complete solution as the union of $2^{N-1}$ parametric ones.

---

**Example for $N=4$.** Let's fix the parities as $(L_1,L_2,L_3,L_4)\equiv (0,1,0,1)\pmod{2}$. Then for $l=2$, have a congruence:
$$3^0\cdot (-1)^{L_1+0-0} \binom{-L_1}{0-0} + 3^1\cdot \big( (-1)^{L_1+1-0} \binom{-L_1}{1-0} + (-1)^{L_2+1-1} \binom{- L_2}{1-1}\big)\equiv 1\pmod{3^2},$$
that is
$$L_1 - 1\equiv 0\pmod{3},$$
and thus $L_1 = 4+6t$, where $t$ is an integer parameter.

Using the above result, we can simplify the congruence for $l=3$ to
$$\frac{L_1 - 1}3 + (-1)^{L_1+2-0} \binom{-L_1}{2-0} + (-1)^{L_2+2-1} \binom{- L_2}{2-1} + (-1)^{L_3+2-2} \binom{- L_3}{2-2} \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$
that is
$$2t - L_2 \equiv 0\pmod{3},$$
implying $L_2 = 3 + 2t + 6s$, where $s$ is an integer parameter.

Next the congruence for $l=4$ simplifies to
$$t^2 + t + s + 1 + L_3 \equiv 0\pmod{3},$$
implying $L_3 = 2(t^2 + t + s + 1) + 6z$, where $z$ is an integer parameter.

Therefore, for the chosen parities, the solutions are described parametrically by
$$\begin{cases}
L_1 = 4+6t, \\
L_2 = 3 + 2t + 6s,\\
L_3 \equiv 2(t^2 + t + s + 1) + 6z,\\
L_4 \equiv 1+2w,
\end{cases}$$
and correspondingly
$$\begin{cases}
M_1 = 4+6t, \\
M_2 = 6s - 4t - 1,\\
M_3 \equiv 6z + 2t^2 - 4s - 1,\\
M_4 \equiv 2w - 2t^2 - 2t - 2s - 6z - 1,
\end{cases}$$
where $t,s,z,w$ are arbitrary integers.

The other $2^3-1 = 7$ parametric solutions (for the other parity choices) are constructed similarly.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} 3^k \, 2^{-L_{k+1}} \equiv 1 \pmod{3^N}$$
is equivalent to a series of equations modulo powers of $3$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
2^{-L_1} &\equiv& 1 \pmod{3} \\
3 \cdot 2^{-L_2} &\equiv& 1 - 2^{-L_1} \pmod{3^2} \\
3^2 \cdot 2^{-L_3} &\equiv& 1 - 2^{-L_1} - 3 \cdot 2^{-L_2} \pmod{3^3} \\
&\vdots&
\end{eqnarray*}$$

We can "lift" solutions rather more efficiently than brute force. As you note, the first is equivalent to $L_1 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$. So for the second we consider the three cases $L_1 \in \{0, 2, 4\} \pmod 6$, getting two solutions:

- $L_1 = 2 \pmod 6, L_2 = 0 \pmod 2$
- $L_1 = 4 \pmod 6, L_2 = 1 \pmod 2$

It's easy via this approach to find the $216$ solutions modulo $(54, 18, 6, 2)$ for $N=4$, and indeed to go up to the $1889568$ solutions for $N=6$. Beyond that the solutions get too numerous to necessarily want to generate them all.